# Problems with IE9 javascript eval()

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

Is there any reason for which

```
eval("(function(x){return x*x;})")
```

doesn't return a function with IE9?

Comment: Do you have IE9 in compatibility mode? (IE8/IE7/Quirks). Try running it in IE9 standards.

Comment: As an aside, people have already mentioned that eval is **evil.**. Let me remind you again that `eval` is _the devil_

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bug in the JScript parser. It shouldn't happen in IE9 unless you are in a Compatibility or Quirks mode.

IE8 misinterprets your function expression as a function declaration, causing it to fail to return anything. Previously mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605969/18936).

You can work around it using one of the other typical ways to unconfuse the JScript parser on what constitutes an expression vs a statement, eg:

```
eval('[function(x){return x*x;}][0]')
eval('0?0:function(x){return x*x;}')
```

Comment: Your linked question implies the issue is not limited to eval. Might be worth mentioning.

Comment: @Raynos: LOL! That's exactly what I just did in my latest (and final) edit.

Answer (score 5):

Due to a parser bug, IE's `eval` cannot directly evaluate a function.

Instead, you should use the `Function` constructor:

```
new Function("x", "return x * x;")
```

Alternatively, you can wrap the eval'd expression in an array:

```
eval("[ function(x){return x*x;} ][0]")
```

IE doesn't object to `eval`ing an array or object that contains a function.

Comment: Could you reference these security reasons or any other kind of microsoft source describing this behaviour.

Comment: @Raynos: Not that I know of.  I can't think of any valid security reason for the behavior, but I can't think of any other reason either.

Comment: then why do you call it "security reasons" instead of a bug? It would also be worthwhile to actually confirm this for IE9 and IE10P2, (I believe you've tested IE8)

Comment: @Raynos: It's remarkably consistent for a bug; it _feels_ like a security fix.  **EDIT**: I take that back.

Comment: I have both IE8 and IE9 available to test with. `alert(typeof eval("(function(x){return x*x;})"));` / http://jsfiddle.net/hkBuQ/show/ in IE8 = `undefined`, in IE9 = `function`. Perhaps the OPs IE9 is not in IE9 mode?

Comment: It's not a security feature; you can return a Function instance no problem, for example with `eval('[function(x){return x*x;}][0]')`. It's a parser-level failure.

Comment: @thirtydot that's the easiest explanation. His IE9 is probably in some form of compatibility mode.

Comment: @SLaks "IE's eval" => "IE<9's eval"

Comment: @thirtydot: True... I forgot the doctype line and IE9 was in "non-standard mode" whatever that means... adding a proper HTML5 doctype line it works as expected

Comment: *"Due to a parser bug, IE's eval cannot directly return a function."* Yes, it can.

Answer (score 2):

```
eval("(function(x){return x*x;})")
```

...works just fine in IE9 in normal mode ([live proof](http://jsbin.com/awudub)) (but see below). Doesn't mean it's a *good idea* (very, very few uses of `eval` qualify as anything other something than to be avoided), but it does work.

It also works (and *should* work) in recent versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.

It *doesn't* seem to work in IE6, IE7, IE8, or IE9 in "compatibility view". That would be a bug (apparently one that's fixed along with about a thousand others with the newer JavaScript engine in IE9), there's nothing wrong with the expression.

You can fix it in earlier versions by forcing the parser to realize it's an expression ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/awudub/4)):

```
eval("(0 || function(x){return x*x;})")
```

Comment: idea theft ¬_¬. At least get it right. (You don't need the brackets at the start and end)

Comment: @Raynos: Not idea theft, great minds. I prefer the parentheses there, for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested it and

```
eval("(function(x){return x*x;})")
```

it returns a function in IE9.

Comment: Are you sure? It doesn't in IE8.  What do you see if you paste `javascript: typeof eval("(function(x){return x*x;})")` in the address bar? (I don't have IE9)

Comment: It works in IE9 mode... I forgot putting the html5 doctype line and so it was working in non-standard mode.